Getting "Error: Specified qdisc kind is unknown." when I try to configure the link attributes in Mininet using WSL2
When I configure links between hosts in a Mininet environment running in WSL2-Ubuntu 20.04 but I get the error message: Error: Specified qdisc kind is unknown. Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory. I'm using  Mininet version 2.3.0.
This is the network topology:
class NetworkTopo( Topo ):
    # Builds network topology
    def build( self, **_opts ):

        s1 = self.addSwitch ( 's1', failMode='standalone' )
        s2 = self.addSwitch ( 's2', failMode='standalone' )
        s3 = self.addSwitch ( 's3', failMode='standalone' )
        s4 = self.addSwitch ( 's4', failMode='standalone' )
        
        
        # Adding hosts
        d1 = self.addHost( 'd1')
        d2 = self.addHost( 'd2')
        d3 = self.addHost( 'd3')

             
        # Connecting hosts to switches
        for d, s in [ (s1, s2), (s1, s3), (d1, s2), (d2, s2), (d3, s3)]:
            # self.addLink( d, s , bw=5, delay='5ms', max_queue_size=1000, loss=10, use_htb=True)
            # self.addLink( d, s, cls=TCLink, bw=1)
            self.addLink( d, s, bw=1, use_htb=True)

topo = NetworkTopo()
    
net = Mininet( topo=topo, link=TCLink, controller=None )
net.start()

This is the error I get:
*** Error: Error: Specified qdisc kind is unknown.
*** Error: RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
Please assist me with solving the issue. Thank you.
I tried to recompile the WSL kernel follwoing this guide: https://alexkaouris.medium.com/run-your-own-kernel-with-wsl2-21e3143e014e
Some guides suggested that I install Mininet from source and I've already done that.

This isn't a problem that can be solved by fixing mininet; it looks like the WSL kernel does not support some of the traffic control features that mininet uses when configuring virtual nodes and links. If you can use something other than link=TCLink you might be able to successfully create a topology. I don't have access to a WSL environment so I can't check myself.

Hi @larsks. Thank you for your response. I decided to use Virtualbox for now.
